# Can I deposit my manuscript in arXiv but I will not publish open access

Tags: publications, preprint

I want to put my paper out in arXiv but due to money shortage I will not be able to publish open access,  I chose subscription. Is it allowed to do this and publish preprint or not?

Answer (score 0):

Check the journal's policies, but usually yes.

[Example policy from Elsevier](https://www.elsevier.com/about/policies/sharing):

> **Preprint**
>
> Authors can share their preprint anywhere at any time.